# PDF Editing software similart to Bluebeam Revu

Tags: windows, pdf

I'm looking for software that is similar to or better than Bluebeam Revu (a PDF editing software). It should have all or at least a majority of the function that Bluebeam Revu has. If you know such software please tell me, thank you very much.

Comment: You should really describe the main features that you want.  As it stands, no one can answer this question unless they have used Bluebeam.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please modify your question so that it is understandable by a person who has never used Bluebeam Revu. Ideally, please remove any mention of Bluebeam Revu and just describe your requirements, then ask us to reopen. Thanks!